# Is it possible to learn some basic mathematics using an app?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, software

I am interested in developing an app for students that are starting a grade career involving mathematics. It is a real problem that they start with almost no knowgladge of basic mathematics and there is no time to teach it in the curricular courses. Is it possible to help they learn some basic properties of operations with real numbers like product, sums and exponents using an app? They are really confused about which operations are "allowed" and which are not. For example when is it correct to cancel two "x" or some doubts that involve operator's precedence. I know that behind this, there is a lack of understanding about the meaning of the equations they write. Do you think is it possible to impart this knowgladge with an app? Do you know any existing app that aims to do this? (i could not find, but I am not good at research). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: dreambox app gets rave reviews. Also, you could look up math app reviews.

Comment: Ever heard of Geogebra?

Comment: Previously asked at [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/194030/64), where it was closed.

Comment: As long as i know geogebra is a geometric learning tool.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about it to write a full answer, but many of my colleagues with young children have said good things about https://dragonbox.com/

Comment: Perhaps Anki alongside with some of those decks: https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/math . Or better, a deck you make yourself.